# Is there a way to migrate test cases & bugs into tfs 2012 from 2010

Tags: tfs2010

Were currently using a custom TFS Workbench template for our stories, testcases and bugs. We are now looking to move across to TFS 2012 and use the new templates that come with that. Is there a way or a utility that we can use to migrate everything across without copy and pasting everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the second link on Google on [TFS](http://blog.damianbrady.com.au/2012/06/03/upgrading-tfs2010-tfs2012-rc-done/) migration. The instructions seem fairly complete and straight forward.  Good luck.